# Make website show as full page on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, web, responsive-design, fullscreen

I am trying to make a website display as a full website whenever it is accessed by an iPhone (or any other phone, hopefully, but iPhone is the spec).

I do not want the page to try to be responsive at all. I want it to look just like the large-screen website, and be useless.

I am using the Genesis theme in Wordpress, but I am open to regular old JavaScript solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme sets the `viewport` to `device-width`. On an iPhone, that would be 320.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You'll want change the meta tag to the width of a full web site, for example, 1200...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200, initial-scale=1">
```

It should then render as if the window were 1200 wide.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

use a **UIWebView** and set the frame like **self.view.bounds** then it will set the frame to the entire page based on device you used..